# Delete file after discord.FFmpegPCMAudio is done playing

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

I want to delete a mp3 file in the same directory after discord.FFmpegPCMAudio is done playing, but i don't know how! I've searched everywhere before posting here, but with no luck.

```
@bot.command(name='play')
async def play(ctx, url):
 global current_audio_file
 voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client

 if voice_client.is_connected():
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel == voice_client.channel:
        try:
            server = ctx.guild
            voice_channel = server.voice_client

            async with ctx.typing():
                if "youtube" or "youtu" in url:
                    result, title = await download_youtube_audio(url)
                    result_b = bytes(result, "utf-8")
                    audio_file_name = codecs.decode(result_b, 'charmap')

                    audio_file, title2 = find_file(audio_file_name, 2)
                elif "spotify" in url:
                    result = await download_spotify_audio(url)
                    result_b = bytes(result, "utf-8")
                    audio_file_name = codecs.decode(result_b, 'charmap')

                    audio_file, title = find_file(audio_file_name, 1)

                if result:
                    if "ERROR" not in result:
                        await ctx.send(f'**Now playing:** {title}')

                        if not voice_channel.is_playing():
                            voice_channel.on_audio_end = lambda e: asyncio.create_task(delete_file(audio_file))

                            voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=audio_file))
                            current_audio_file = audio_file
                        else:
                            await ctx.send("Another song is playing right now!")
                    else:
                        print(f"An error occurred while trying to download the audio. Error: {result}")
                        send_error(ctx, Exception(result))
                else:
                    await ctx.send("An error occurred while trying to download the audio.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            send_error(ctx, e)
            await ctx.send("An error occurred while trying to play the audio.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not in the same voice channel as the bot.")
else:
    await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")

def delete_file(filename: str):
if os.path.exists(filename):
    os.remove(filename)
    print(f"Deleted {filename}")
```

If anyone knows how to do it, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the mp3 file after audio playback, you can use the on_audio_end event of the VoiceChannel object. Make sure to assign the event before starting audio playback. Here is one way to do this:

```
@bot.command(name='play')
async def play(ctx, url):
    global current_audio_file
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client

    if voice_client.is_connected():
        if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel == voice_client.channel:
            try:
                server = ctx.guild
                voice_channel = server.voice_client

                async with ctx.typing():
                    if "youtube" or "youtu" in url:
                        result, title = await download_youtube_audio(url)
                        result_b = bytes(result, "utf-8")
                        audio_file_name = codecs.decode(result_b, 'charmap')

                        audio_file, title2 = find_file(audio_file_name, 2)
                    elif "spotify" in url:
                        result = await download_spotify_audio(url)
                        result_b = bytes(result, "utf-8")
                        audio_file_name = codecs.decode(result_b, 'charmap')

                        audio_file, title = find_file(audio_file_name, 1)

                    if result:
                        if "ERROR" not in result:
                            await ctx.send(f'**Now playing:** {title}')

                            if not voice_channel.is_playing():
                                voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=audio_file))
                                current_audio_file = audio_file

                                # Define o evento on_audio_end para excluir o arquivo após a reprodução
                                voice_channel.on_audio_end = lambda e: asyncio.create_task(delete_file(audio_file))
                            else:
                                await ctx.send("Another song is playing right now!")
                        else:
                            print(f"An error occurred while trying to download the audio. Error: {result}")
                            send_error(ctx, Exception(result))
                    else:
                        await ctx.send("An error occurred while trying to download the audio.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
                send_error(ctx, e)
                await ctx.send("An error occurred while trying to play the audio.")
        else:
            await ctx.send("You are not in the same voice channel as the bot.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")

async def delete_file(filename: str):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        os.remove(filename)
        print(f"Deleted {filename}")
```

This implementation uses on_audio_end to call the delete_file function and delete the file after the audio has been played. Be sure to set the event before starting playback.

Comment: Btw if you haven't read my code. It's exactly the same and it doesn't work! Like the delete_file() function doesnt get called.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to delete an MP3 file in the same directory after the `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio` is done playing. To achieve this, you can use the `on_audio_end` callback provided by the `voice_channel.play` method. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```py
import os
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command(name='play')
async def play(ctx, url):
    global current_audio_file
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client

    if voice_client.is_connected():
        if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel == voice_client.channel:
            try:
                server = ctx.guild
                voice_channel = server.voice_client

                async with ctx.typing():
                    if "youtube" or "youtu" in url:
                        result, title = await download_youtube_audio(url)
                        result_b = bytes(result, "utf-8")
                        audio_file_name = codecs.decode(result_b, 'charmap')

                        audio_file, title2 = find_file(audio_file_name, 2)
                    elif "spotify" in url:
                        result = await download_spotify_audio(url)
                        result_b = bytes(result, "utf-8")
                        audio_file_name = codecs.decode(result_b, 'charmap')

                        audio_file, title = find_file(audio_file_name, 1)

                    if result:
                        if "ERROR" not in result:
                            await ctx.send(f'**Now playing:** {title}')

                            if not voice_channel.is_playing():
                                voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=audio_file))
                                current_audio_file = audio_file

                                # Set up the on_audio_end callback to delete the file
                                voice_channel.on_audio_end = lambda e: asyncio.create_task(delete_file(audio_file))

                            else:
                                await ctx.send("Another song is playing right now!")
                        else:
                            print(f"An error occurred while trying to download the audio. Error: {result}")
                            send_error(ctx, Exception(result))
                    else:
                        await ctx.send("An error occurred while trying to download the audio.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
                send_error(ctx, e)
                await ctx.send("An error occurred while trying to play the audio.")
        else:
            await ctx.send("You are not in the same voice channel as the bot.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")

def delete_file(filename: str):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        os.remove(filename)
        print(f"Deleted {filename}")
```

In this modified code, I added the `voice_channel.on_audio_end` callback to delete the audio file after playback is finished. The `delete_file` function remains the same as in your original code.

Now, when the audio playback is finished, the `delete_file` function will be called to delete the audio file. Make sure to adjust the code as needed to fit the rest of your bot's functionality and error handling.